# Django: Custom formset validation + url slug

Tags: django, django-forms

How do I get the slug organizer from my url in my class BaseReserveFormSet? Anyone did that before? I am really struggling how to solve that.

BaseFormSet:

```
class BaseReserveFormSet(BaseFormSet):

    def clean(self):   
        queryset = Organizer.objects.filter(
            # MY PROBLEM: HOW DO I GET <slug:organizer> IN HERE?
            slug='lorem-2',
        )
        max_qty_per_ticket = queryset.first().max_qty_per_ticket
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:organizer>/<slug:event>/', event_detail_view, name='event'),
]
```

Answer (score -1):

I quickly want to answer my own question. Maybe it helps someone another time.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual code as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.